# Missing edit button on node page

Tags: entities, users

Im allowing authenticated users to add field values on existing nodes on my site using the "[Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)" module. I`ve set up the necessary custom permissions in the "manage fields" screen:

[image]

However, an authenticated user is never shown the "Edit" button on the node page:
[image]

If everything where working, the user should have a "Edit" button to be able to add field values. What`s wrong?

Comment: Impossible to debug from here. Maybe some module blocks edit anyway? Maybe user does not have permission to text format used in given node? Maybe theme is flawed and simply fails to render that button? Maybe something else entirely.

Comment: OK, its not the theme. Ive checked.

Comment: List of things you already checked should be in the question directly. Preferably with info on *how* you checked.

Comment: Have you tested to narrow it to a display or permission issue? For example, having the auth user navigate to */node/<NID>/edit* to see if they can access the node edit form.

Answer (score 2):

The [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) is so the field shows up, they can see it, when they are editing the node.

The problem here looks to be that they don't have permission to edit the content type node.

Ex:

- Allow to Edit Own Articles
- Allow to Edit All Articles